# Question about kernel of a homomorphic function relating to the characteristic of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity.  If there is a smallest positive integer $n$ such that $n1_R=0_R$, then $R$ is said to have characteristic $n$.

Also the kernel of a function is defined for a function $f:R\rightarrow S$ as $K=\{r\in R\mid f(r)=0_S\}$

1a Let $R$ be a ring with identity.  Show that the map $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ given by $f(k)=k1_R$ is a homomorphism.

1b) Show that the kernel of $f$ is the ideal $(n)$, where $n$ is the characteristic of $R$

I have done 1a.  My questions are for 1b.

I know that if for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ where $n>0$, $n1_R\neq 0$, then the characteristic of $R$ is zero, since the only way that $n1_R= 0$ is when $n=0$.  Also, in the case where if there exist a smallest $n$ such that $n1_R=0$, then the ring $R$ is said to have characteristic $n$. If I let kernel of $f(n)=n1_R$, to be defined as $K=\{n\in \mathbb{Z}\mid f(n)=nl_R=0\}$.  $R$ having characteristic zero would be $K\neq\{0_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$ and $R$ having characteristic $n$ would be $K=\{0_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$.  I am not sure for which cases of the kernel, whether it is $K\neq\{0_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$, or $K=\{0_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$ that would allow me to show that it is equal to the ideal $(n)$.  I need to show $K\subset (n)$ and $(n) \subset K$.  Lastly, if I know what the kernel is for either cases, I can use the first isomorphism theorem for rings to show in the former, it is isomorphic to ${\mathbb{Z}}$ while in the latter case is isomorphic to ${\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$. I am not sure if that will resolve the question.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: One note: wherever you write "smallest $n$", you actually mean "smallest positive".

Comment: @AryamanMaithani thank you for pointing that out.  I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: I didn't quite exactly follow your line of reasoning but maybe this helps you: Do you know that the kernel is an ideal of $\Bbb Z$? Do you know what ideals of $\Bbb Z$ look like?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $(n)$ and every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal.  But I don't know how to show that the kernel is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.  I mean, the kernel is describing the characteristic of a ring and it is either zero, or it is $n$.

Comment: That is a true fact about ring homomorphism in general. But even without all that, you can try proving it yourself for this particular case. This should not be too tough using that the fact that $0_R + 0_R = 0_R$ and $k \cdot 0_R = 0_R$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani when the question ask to show that the kernel of $f$ is equal to the ideal $(n)$, is it asking me to show that it is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ where every ideal in it is principal or is it asking me to show that it is equal to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  Also, i can say that it is either $K\neq\{0_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$, or $K=\{0_{\mathbb{Z}}\}$.  In the first case, by the first isomorphism theorem, $\mathbb{Z}/K\cong \mathbb{Z}$. In the second case, applying the first isomorphism theorem, $\mathbb{Z}/K\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  I am not sure if this answers the question.

Comment: It is asking you to show that $\ker f$ is an _ideal_ of $\Bbb Z$. More specifically, it is asking you to show that it is the ideal $(n) \subset \Bbb Z$, where $n$ is the characteristic of the ring. The first isomorphism theorem then tells you that $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani the kernel is either $\{0_\mathbb{Z}\}$ or is not $\{0_\mathbb{Z}\}$, in the first case, $f(n)=n1_R\neq 0$ for all $n>0$ which means $K=\{0_\mathbb{Z}\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ and in the later case $f(n)=n1_R=0$ for some smallest positive integer $n$, so  $K=(n)\subset \mathbb{Z}$.  Is this how to resolve the question?

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrect about  $K $.  What happens is $K=\{0\} $ precisely when  $\rm {char}R=0$.  Otherwise,  if $\rm {char}R=n $ we get $K=(n) $.

The proof is straight forward.   Suppose  $f (k)=0$.  Then $k\cdot1_R=0$.  So $n\mid k $ (technically you should probably use the Euclidean algorithm here), or $k\in (n) $.  Conversely,  say $k\in (n) $.   We have  $k=mn $, then $f (k)=mn\cdot1_R=m (n\cdot1_R)=m (0)=0 $.

Comment: I think I have forgotten something when I was doing the question. There was an example in my text which show that the surjective homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with its kernel being $(n)$.  This question is similar, except the map is given as $f(n)=n1_R$ where the image of $f$ describes the characteristic of the ring $R$.....

Comment: ...I have a few questions about your answer if that is ok.  In one direction of your proof, when you wrote: "Suppose  $f(k)=0$.  Then $k\cdot1_R=0$.  So $n\mid k$".  When $k\cdot1_R=0$, then $k\cdot1_R=0\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and $k\cdot1_R\equiv 0\ (mod\ n)$ which implies $n\mid k$ and hence $k\in (n)$.  For the converse direction, when you wrote "$k=mn $, then $f (k)=mn\cdot1_R=m (n\cdot1_R)=m (0)=0 $.", this is the direction where it takes care of the characteristic zero case?  Is that correct?

Comment: I was actually doing the case where the characteristic is nonzero.   When the characteristic is $0$ you can prove that $K=\{0\} $, in a similar fashion.  Clearly  $0\in K $.  And also  $K\subset\{0\} $, since by the definition of characteristic  $k\cdot1_R\ne0$ for any nonzero  $k $.

Comment: okay okay, that is what I thought in the case of $K=\{0_\mathbb{Z}\}$.  I often get confused when reading questions.  Sometime I still have trouble translating into math notations what the question is asking of the reader to do.  Does it happen less to people as they go on in math?

Comment: also, thank you so much for your explanations.